# How to get guild info of all the members of my server

Tags: python, dictionary, discord, discord.py, embed

I want to get guild information of all the members of my server, and then show top 10 members of guild member who have the most coins

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        guildInfo = json.load(f)

    guildInfo[guild.id] = guild.text_channels[0]
    
    
    with open("mainbank.json"), "w" as f:
        json.dump(guildInfo, f)
         

@client.command(aliases = ['gd'])
async def guild(ctx):
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
      guildInfo = json.load(f)

    channel = guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id]
    await ctx.send (embed=channel)
```

The above code is giving this error

```
Ignoring exception in command guild:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 501, in guild
    channel = guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id]
KeyError: 884811895884894218

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 884811895884894218
```

I am using this code for the leaderboard and it is working perfectly for all the members in my server but I want it to show top 10 between the guild members

```
@client.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def leaderboard(ctx,x = 10):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)

    total = sorted(total,reverse=True)    

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"<:emoji_23:886988033872764938> : TOP {x} RICHEST PEOPLES OF ALL TIME..." , description = "This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet",color = discord.Color(0x00FFFC))
    index = 1
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = await client.fetch_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name = f"{index}. {name}  " , value = f" 「Balance」 ❯❯ {amt} ",  inline = False)
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

I am using this code for the leaderboard and it is working perfectly for all the members in my server but I want it to show top 10 between the guild members

```
{"555463650358329354": {"wallet": 87, "bank": 6969, "bag": [{"item": "watch", "amount": 0}]}, "886271151729414154": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "525961784297914378": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "680988467270123522": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "725722170206060624": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "517879304562933780": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "706831502859698226": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 7400, "bag": [{"item": "watch", "amount": 1}]}, "781446116955914260": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969, "bag": [{"item": "watch", "amount": 1}]}, "875681501696643102": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "599611694746042380": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "786899180240502804": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "537275315530104832": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "632848175992012825": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "704319968183058492": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 7099}, "864813571501195315": {"wallet": 183, "bank": 6969}, "755771702947872818": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969, "bag": [{"item": "watch", "amount": 0}]}, "570601939809599489": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "789018134228762645": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "742642664129953822": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "886651528469971025": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 0}, "768162376003878994": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 6969}, "854389490021564456": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 51332}}
```

above is the conents of mainbank.json

Comment: send contents of mainbank.json

Comment: added@WasiMaster

Comment: Make sure you have all intents enabled

Comment: the json keys are strings while the keys you are using to access are ints. convert them to str first

Comment: in which line exactly? @WasiMaster

Comment: @HireshVerma it's literally in the error

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up the result of the comments;

You firstly have to convert `ctx.message.guild.id` to a string with `channel = guildInfo[str(ctx.message.guild.id)]` as the JSON File also got the Guild IDs as strings (e.g. `"555463650358329354": {"wallet": 87,...`)

Btw it's line

> File "main.py", line !! 501 !!, in guild

:)